# Login page theming?

Tags: templates, login

is there a way for me to add a page to my template directory to customize my `login.php` page?

I couldn't find much on the subject so I decided to post the question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some actions and filters on wordpress you can use to customize your login page:
Here are some i found in the wp-login.php file

action `login_head`  , to output html before the header tag is closed

filter `login_headerurl` to customize the link where the logo goes

filter `login_headertitle` to customize the title of the logo

filter `login_message` to customize the error messages

filter `wp_admin_css` to edit the css used by the admin

action `login_footer` to add any htmk in the bodytag is closed

The logo comes from the css rule `h1 a`

All hooks and actions can be added on your theme functions.php or within a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own page and paste this code in page.php where you want to show login form 
or check wp-admin/css/color-fress.css go and edit little bit css there

```
     $home=get_bloginfo('url');
     $url="http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if($url==$home."/YOUR-SLUG-FOR-LOGIN-PAGE)
        {
             wp_login_form(); 
        }
```